# How to properly implement a factory for templated products

Tags: c++, templates, factory, abstract-factory

I think this task is very common, but I cannot find a proper solution to it.

I have a hierarchy of "products" which have some "traits", so I decided to use templated interface for products, where the template parameter is the "trait":

These are traits:

```
struct Foo {
    static std::string get_name() { return "Foo"; }

    Foo(int a) : a_(a) {}
    int operator()() const { return a_; }

private:
    int a_;
};

struct Bar {
    static std::string get_name() { return "Bar"; }

    Bar(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
    int operator()() const { return a_ + b_; }

private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

struct Spam {
    Spam(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(0) {}
    void operator()() { c_++; }

private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
    int c_;
};
```

And these are products hierarchy:

```
template <class T>
class Product {

public:
    typedef T T_type;

    virtual T get() = 0;

    virtual ~Product() {}
};

template <class T>
class ProductA : public Product<T> {

    typedef Product<T>   base_type;

public:
    ProductA(int a) : a_(a) {}

    virtual ~ProductA() {}

    virtual T get() { 
        return T(a_); 
    }

private:
    int a_;
};

template <class T, class U>
class ProductB : public Product<T> {

    typedef Product<T>                                  base_type;

public:
    typedef U                                           U_type;

    ProductB(int a, int b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

    virtual ~ProductB();

    virtual T get() { 
        init(); // U is being used here
        return T(a_, b_); 
    }

protected:
    void init() {}

private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
};
```

I need to use additional level of inheritance because of different interfaces of `ProductA` and `ProductB` - they have different c-tors.

And here are concrete products:

```
class ProductA1 : public ProductA<Foo> {

    typedef ProductA<Foo>  base_type;

public:
    ProductA1(int a) : base_type(a) { std::cout << "A1 created" << std::endl; }

    virtual ~ProductA1() { std::cout << "A1 deleted" << std::endl; }
};

class ProductB1 : public ProductB<Bar, Spam> {

    typedef ProductB<Bar, Spam>  base_type;

public:
    ProductB1(int a, int b) : base_type(a, b) { std::cout << "B1 created" << std::endl; }

    virtual ~ProductB1() { std::cout << "B1 deleted" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now I want to have a mechanism of "unified" creation of products (in this example of two types `ProductA1` and `ProductB1`) somehow with the string passed into some method. Obviously I need the Factory...

So I implemented factories for different branches of the hierarchy (to create objects of types `ProductA` and `ProductB`) so that I could create objects passing their types through the template parameter:

```
template <class P>
struct ProductAFactory {

    typedef typename P::T_type      T_type;
    typedef ProductA<T_type>        product_type;

    static 
    product_type* create(int a) { 
        return new P(a); 
    }
};


template <class P>
struct ProductBFactory {

    typedef typename P::T_type      T_type;
    typedef typename P::U_type      U_type;
    typedef ProductB<T_type,
                     U_type>        product_type;

    static
    product_type* create(int a, int b) {
        return new P(a, b);
    }
};
```

Having these factories I have to have a factory supposed to construct products of necessary type and return a pointer to product of the `Product<T>` interface:

```
template <class T>
class ProductFactory {

public:

    static 
    Product<T>*
    create(const std::string& product_name, 
           const int a, 
           const int b) {

        const std::string product_a1 = "A1";
        const std::string product_b1 = "B1";

        if (product_name == product_a1)
            return ProductAFactory<ProductA1>::create(a);
        else if (product_name == product_b1)
            return ProductBFactory<ProductB1>::create(a, b); // (*) <--- compiler error
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported product: " + product_name);
    }
};
```

All these codes are intended to be used in such a way:

```
void main() {

    typedef Foo T;

    std::shared_ptr<Product<T>> p(ProductFactory<T>::create("A1", 1, 1));
    T t = p->get(); 

    std::cout << t.get_name() << ": " << t() << std::endl;
}
```

And here I faced with a problem of compiling this code - the error is `return value type does not match the function type` at `(*)`. It seems that `ProductB<Foo, Spam>` cannot be converted automatically into its base type `Product<Foo>`...

I'm not a good factory developer, maybe I don't understand base principles and concepts. Could anybody help to correct this code or this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When recreating this, the error I get is (slightly different to what you published):

```
error: cannot convert 'ProductBFactory<ProductB1>::product_type* {aka ProductB<Bar, Spam>*}' to 'Product<Foo>*' in return
         return ProductBFactory<ProductB1>::create(a, b); // (*) <--- compiler error
```

The crux of the issue is that you're trying to return a `ProductB<Bar, Spam>*` from a function declared to return `Product<Foo>*`. You seem to think that these types are somehow related by inheritance, but they're not at all. `ProductB<Bar, Spam>` is in fact a subclass of `Product<Bar>` - this last one is not in any way related or convertable to a `Product<Foo>` any more than a `vector<int>` is to a `vector<float>` - i.e. not at all. Template classes with different template parameters are totally distinct from each other.

So either you have made a mistake in your code, and are trying to return a `ProductB<Bar,Spam>*` when in fact you should be trying to return a `ProductB<Foo,Spam>*` (say), or you misunderstand the polymorphic relationship (or lack thereof) between template inheritance hierarchies with different template parameters.

**UPDATE:** In response to your comment: It is possible to create a factory that creates objects of different templated types as long as they have a common ancestor in the type hierarchy which can be used as the return type. In your case this requires a re-design at least to some extent. One way to do that would be to create a base class for `Product<T>`, say `ProductBase`, that doesn't depend on a template:

```
template <class T>
class Product : public ProductBase
{
    ...
};
```

Then the return type of your `create` function can be `ProductBase*`. Equivalently, you can just take out the template out of the definition of `Product` itself. Either way, this will require some further changes to the interface to make it useful.

For example, see this [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b4248ee26a029a), where I implement the `ProductBase` approach. Your example can thus be made to compile, but only thanks to a nasty `static_cast` introduced in the main function. This is the sort of issue that you have to resolve by changing your base interface appropriately.

Comment: Ok, maybe I realy misunderstand the polymorphic relationship between templates, but could you advise how this problem could be solved? Is it possible to implement a factory that creates object of templated type?

Comment: ``You seem to think that these types are somehow related by inheritance`` - of course, I don't :) I wrote this code to demonstrate a concept - it won't compile because in one function two different types are returned.

Comment: See my update to the answer above, including the live demo

Comment: thank you for the advise and demo. I think that it would be realy better to make a re-design. Thank you.